# Error with Threads in Tcl - No Such Variable Error When Sourcing within thread

Tags: multithreading, tcl

Getting an error, can't read "chan" no such variable, that is contained within a file I am sourcing within the thread in another file, chan is not even in the file I am using with my threads.

```
thread::send $function {

        source xyz
        source zyx
        source yzx

}
```

xyz contains a variable that is completed unrelated to this file, but is giving me an error "cant read "chan" no such variable while executing "ProcedureInOtherFile "Event completed" $chan"  invoked from within "source xyz"

Comment: Could you improve your description, by providing an actual example that matches your situation? I am afraid, the way you describe your perceived problem is not particularly helpful. See my attempt to provide you with a sandboxed REPL example.

Answer (score 2):

> chan is not even in the file I am using with my threads.

Exactly :) What are you expectations? You seem to `source` some existing Tcl scripts in a black-box manner, without fulfilling their callee requirements.

Watch:

```
% package req Thread
2.8.2
% set fh [open "/tmp/foo.tcl" w]
file5
% puts $fh {puts $chan "hello world"}
% close $fh
% set t1 [thread::create]
tid0x700004a5c000
% thread::send $t1 { source /tmp/foo.tcl }
can't read "chan": no such variable
% thread::send $t1 { set chan stderr; source /tmp/foo.tcl }
hello world
% thread::release $t1
0
% exit
```

Comment: To add to this answer, remember that each thread has its own interpreter with its own variables. They are not shared; you have to pass things over explicitly if you want them to be there. Also, channels other than the standard ones (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) are only visible in their originating interpreter by default.